# How to extract specific json data in java

Tags: java

I am trying to extract from the following data:

```
{
  "USD" : {"15m" : 478.68, "last" : 478.68, "buy" : 478.55, "sell" : 478.68,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "JPY" : {"15m" : 51033.99, "last" : 51033.99, "buy" : 51020.13, "sell" : 51033.99,  "symbol" : "¥"},
}
```

I want to get the USD last price.

my code so far is as follows:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL("https://blockchain.info/ticker").openStream()));
System.out.println(json.get("USD"));
```

This gives me the following output:

```
{"symbol":"$","last":651.98,"buy":651.02,"sell":651.98,"15m":651.98}
```

I just want to get the last USD Price, i have no idea how to do it! Can anyone enlighten me.

Thanks!

Comment: try - json.getJSONObject("USD").getString("last")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL("https://blockchain.info/ticker").openStream()));
double last = json.getJSONObject("USD").getDouble("last");
```

Comment: That did it thanks